# A oder b ist/sind

Tags: grammar

Folgender Satz war Ausgangspunkt einer Diskussion mit unserer Doku-Abteilung:

> "Unbefugte Vervielfältigung oder unbefugter Vertrieb dieses Programms oder eines Teils davon sind strafbar."

Ist der Satz so grammatikalisch richtig?
Die Duden-Rechtschreibprüfung sagt nein und schlägt vor, "sind" in "ist" zu ändern.

Da Vervielfältigung und Vertrieb aber beide strafbar sind, wäre aber wohl sowieso besser, "oder" in "und" zu ändern?

Erstaunlich ist allerdings, dass laut Google der Satz exakt in der obigen Form sehr häufig verwendet wird.

Comment: Versuch es doch so: "Sowohl unbefugte Vervielfältigung als auch unbefugter Vertrieb dieses Programms oder eines Teiles davon sind strafbar." Dann ist es eindeutig "sind". Die Verwendung von "und", wie du schon erwähnst macht es auch einfach: "sind", ich weiß aber nicht, ob man dann juristisch später sagen kann: Da steht aber das nur die Kombination strafbar ist (um etwas pingelig zu sein). Andererseits, wenn man nen Strick drausdrehen will, kann man es auch bei "oder".

Comment: Ja, das kann man sicher noch etwas klarer formulieren. Meine eigentliche Frage ist aber, ob der Satz in der ursprünglichen Formulierung "oder ... sind" wirklich falsch ist.

Comment: Anmerkung: Nicht auf die Frage bezogen, aber ich würde auf das doppelte *unbefugt* verzichten. Klingt nicht gut in dem Satz.

Comment: Auf das doppelte "unbefugt" können wir nicht verzichten, da wir ja unsere Vertriebsmitarbeiter nicht ins Gefängnis bringen wollen :)

Comment: Hahahaha :) Wie wär's mit unberechtigt, unerlaubt, illegal, verboten, ... Und im Falle eines "und" würde sich doch das *unbefugt* auf Vervielfältigung und Vertrieb beziehen, dann sind die wieder frei ;)

Comment: Die Antworten bevorzugen "ist" und das ist wohl auch durch den Duden belegt. Das Hauptargument ist, dass es sich um Entitäten im Singular handelt. Auch das ist richtig... rein technisch. Allerdings heißt es im zur Diskussion stehenden Satz eben NICHT "eine" oder die, sondern es wird auf einen Artikel verzichtet. Das impliziert so etwas wie jegliche oder alle... der Singular steht, da juristisch schon eine einzige ausreicht um belangt zu werden. Aber durch das Fehlen eines Artikels schwingt ein Plural zumindest mit und daher klingt "sind" in dem Beispiel für mich kein bisschen falsch.

Comment: Wäre es "eine" und "ein", dann wäre sind klar falsch und würde sich auch falsch anfühlen. Das tut es hier, zumindest für mich, nicht, da der einzige Numerus-Indikator das Nomen selbst ist und das ist wenig...also... auch wenn es grammatisch "ist" sein müsste, so würde ich tatsächlich sind als "passender" empfinden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wenn die Subjektteile mit oder, entweder...oder oder beziehungsweise verknüpft sind und im Singular stehen, steht das Verb meistens im Singular.

Daher:

> "Unbefugte Vervielfältigung oder unbefugter Vertrieb dieses Programms oder eines Teils davon **ist** strafbar."

Gibt es eine Vermischung von Plural- oder Singularwörtern ist durchaus beides richtig. [*] Genaueres dazu und Beispiele finden sich auf [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-23240). Dort wird auch erwähnt, dass in Ausnahmefällen auch der Plural bei Singularobjekten Verwendung finden kann, aber ob dein Beispiel zu den Ausnahmen gehört... Ich denke nicht.

---

[*] Bitte hierzu die Hinweise auf canoo.net beachten!

Answer (score 6):

Hier werden zwei singuläre Entitäten verglichen (die *eine* Vervielfältigung oder der *eine* Vertrieb), folglich ist nur die Verwedung des Singulars (*ist*) korrekt.